# How can I compare Long and Int with assertEquals. Junit Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, junit, kotlin

How can I compare Long and Int with assertEquals with Kotlin and Junit

for example

```
var size: Int = 20
var totalElements: Long = 20
assertEquals(size, totalElements)

java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.lang.Integer<20> but was: java.lang.Long<20>
Expected :java.lang.Integer<20> 
Actual   :java.lang.Long<20>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to convert both numbers to the same type, e.g.:

`assertEquals(size.toLong(), totalElements)`

This converts `size` to a Long; and `totalElements` is already a `Long`, so the compiler can infer a `Long` type for `assertEquals()`.  It's slightly awkward, but compiles and does what you want.

(Of course, you could instead convert to `Int`s (or another numeric type), but that's not as good because it could give false positives if `totalElements` is outside the range of an Int.)

This is a little more awkward than Java, because Kotlin is more careful about the numeric conversions it does; as with its improved null checking, this can expose potential errors that Java won't.

Oddly enough, when I tried your code, it wouldn't even compile: it fails with a ‘Type inference failed’ error.  (I'm using kotlinc-jvm 1.3.11.)  Once again, Kotlin spots problems at compile time!